# How do I match a command line argument in an if condition?

Tags: bash

I want to read from a yml file line by line and want to check if a command line argument is in the line, if it is I want to put the entire line in a different file.

Below is the simplified version of the code I am working with.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ".*$1:" ]]; then
        echo "$line" >> file_copy.yml
    fi
done < file.yml
```

I have tried `"$line" == *".*\$1:"*` but it didn't work.

Edit:

As soon as I pass a command line argument it says there is a syntax error.

Comment: To add to my above post, I am making a new command via alias so that command line argument will come when that command is called and this whole code is inside that alias.

Comment: Why not just `grep … file.yml >> file_copy.yml`?

Comment: @Biffen I want to handle some variable assignments as well and some other checks inside of this if. Will that be possible with grep?

Comment: Also, putting something of this complexity in an alias is asking for trouble. Use a function or a script instead.

Comment: ‘_Will that be possible with grep?_’ It might be, depending on what it is. Otherwise `awk` might be a good option.

Comment: Yeah I will be eventually moving this into a different function, and I will call that function from the alias.

Comment: Simply use _pattern matching_: `if [[ $line = *"$1:"* ]]; then …`

Answer (score 0):

u can not quote regex expression; for example:

```
if [[ "abc" =~ ".*a" ]]; then echo "true"; fi    # --> This error

if [[ "abc" =~ .*a ]]; then echo "true"; fi      # --> This ok
```

[doc](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693361/unix-tip-using-bash-s-regular-expressions.html)

> this may work

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
if [[ "$line" =~ .*$1: ]]; then
    echo "$line" >> file_copy.yml
fi
done < file.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, The problem is, it gives me a syntax error near the argument that I pass in command line. This happened in my original code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see whether `$1` is a literal substring of `$line`,

```
 [[ $line == *$1* ]]
```

would test it; no regex matching needed.

Comment: I also want to ensure there is a ":" after the command line argument passed and there could be some spaces before it starts on the line. Checked this as well but it is giving me syntax error only when I pass a command line argument.

Comment: Where do you say this requirement in your question? The spaces incidedntally don't matter. My command searches for a substring somewhere, and of course `line` may contain spaces at the start of the string. If you want to ensure a colon, just test `$ine == *$1:`  instead. However, my feeling is that you just did not specify precisely enough what exactly you want to test here.